# How to check if array contains more than one element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I would like to ensure that an array contains **more then one** element and that it is not null nor undefined. With other words: I am looking for an alternative to

```
if(array && array.length > 1)
```

that would be better to read.

Lodash provides a method for checking if an array contains **at least one** element:

```
if(_.some(array))
```

Is there a similar method for checking for several elements?

Unfortunately following methods do not exist:

```
if(_.several(array))

if(_.many(array))
```

Would I have to write my own extension method or did I just not find the right lodash command, yet?

Comment: for me `array.length > 1` is a lot more readable then `_.some(array)`

Comment: Looks like you are overthinking here. `_.some` is not meant for the purpose you mentioned. It's much more powerful. For you purpose writing a function which wraps `array.length > 1` more than suffices.

Comment: @Stoyan _.some(array) would compare to array && array.length > 0. I am reading from left to right and when getting to "some" and see the argument I already know what the condition is about. Otherwise I need to proceed to "length" and even then I have to check what comes after length: <, > ===, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create own lodash mixin for that:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
var anotherArray = [4];

function several(array) {
  return _.get(array, 'length') > 1
}

_.mixin({ 'several': several });

console.log(_.several(myArray)) // ==> true
console.log(_.several(anotherArray)) // ==> false
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ecq7ddey/

Answer (score 2):

```
_.compact(array).length > 1
```

Compact returns array with falsey values removed (false, null, 0, "", undefined, and NaN).

Answer (score 2):

This is the `atLeast()` function, which works like `_.some()`, but accepts a min number. If the callback returns `true` a number of times that is identical to `min`, the function will return `true`.

```js
 // the parameters order is to maintain compatability with lodash. A more functional order would be - cb, min, arr
function atLeast(arr, min, cb) {
  cb = cb || _.identity; // default is like some
  
  var counter = 0;
  return _.some(arr, function(v) {
    cb(v) && counter++;
    
    return counter === min;
  });
}

_.mixin({ 'atLeast': atLeast });

var arr1 = [1, 0, null, undefined];
var arr2 = [null, undefined, 0];

var isNotNil = _.negate(_.isNil); // not null or undefined

console.log(_.atLeast(arr1, 2, isNotNil));

console.log(_.atLeast(arr2, 2, isNotNil));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```